# None of my sites products are logging correctly into localStorage

Tags: javascript

Alrighty, so background. I'm coding a site for a huge class project, presentation and all that annoying stuff. This site is an eCommerce site selling what would be tech products, most of our inspiration for it coming from stuff like MicroSoft. My job is to write a working cart and checkout system written in HTML/CSS, JS, and PHP, and then have "bought" items log into an SQL database, and I have a little under 2 more months to finish it.

**Now**, my issue currently is that, on click of the add to cart button of a specific product, the wrong one is logged into localStorage and thats obviously a serious issue.

I wrote this simple list to handle the items actually being "sold", and some other javascript to support it.
I could also use some help to see how I can code this better.

For example, if say, 64S is clicked, 32T is logged, 32S as well as 32T logs 16T, and 128S logs bitface.
Everything else logs OS.

```
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('#add-cart');

let products = [
  {
    name:'Macro OS',
    tag:'OS',
    price:29.99,
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:'MacroHard 16T',
    tag:'16T',
    price:499.99,
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:'MacroHard 32T',
    tag:'32T',
    price:629.99,
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:'MacroHard BitFace',
    tag:'BitFace',
    price:499.99,
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:'Macrohard 16S',
    tag:'16S',
    price:299.99,
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:'MacroHard 32S',
    tag:'32S',
    price:399.99,
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:'MacroHard 64S',
    tag:'64S',
    price:499.99,
    inCart:0
  },
  {
    name:'MacroHard 128S',
    tag:'128S',
    price:599.99,
    inCart:0
  }
];
```

**Anyway**, heres the main function that handles the addition of these items into localStorage, and its where I guarantee the issue is coming from. I just cant seem to figure out how to fix it though.
If you want to see the rest of my code, I can write the rest of my javascript/HTML

```
function setItems(product) {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

  if (cartItems != null) {
    cartItems = {
      ...cartItems,
      [product.tag]: product
    };

    cartItems[product.tag].inCart += 1;
  } else {
    product.inCart = 1;
    cartItems = {
      [product.tag]: product
    };
  }
  localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}
```

Comment: As a tip no elements can't have the same id attribute in the DOM

Comment: I should really research DOM stuff a bit more, but yeah i usually tend to avoid giving elements the same ID ofc, I just changed it to classes, but i have to same issue